# Solving set of equations in R (reals)

Tags: number-theory

Can we solve the following set of equations in R? If yes, what are the methods or procedure to find solutions of the following set of equations. Please explain.

$x + y + z = a$

$px + qy + rz = b$

$p^2$x + $q^2$ y +$ r^2$z = $c$

$p^3$x + $q^3$ y +$ r^3$z = $d$

$p^4$x + $q^4$ y +$ r^4$z = $e$

$p^5$x + $q^5$ y +$ r^5$z = $f$

Narosa Nair

Comment: Are you familiar with linear algebra or solving systems of equations?

Comment: I am bit of familiar with linear algebra/system of matrices etc

Answer (score 1):

Since the equations are polynomials, they can be solved using Groebner basis techniques.  They are many implementations of Groebner bases, including ones built into Mathematica and Maple.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that the values of the rhs are known, you have a system of 6 equations for 6 unknowns (x, y, z, p, q, r). Then, the system could be solved numerically (I do not suppose that a symbolic solution exists). The system is formed of nonlinear equations the Jacobian of which being quite simple to establish. Newton-Raphson method is probably a very good candidate ..... provided that "good" starting values be available.

Comment: ! could you solve for some unknown values for me.

Comment: Or can you show me few steps to proceed the solutions

Comment: The idea of Newton-Raphson method for multivariable nonlinear systems is to expand each of the equation as a first order Taylor series around a given point. So, now, you face a system of linear (linearized) equations; solve them and you obtain a new guess. Continue until you converge to the desired accuracy. The key point is the quality of the starting point (in N dimensions).